# Program in python that prompts user to input a number of quarters, dimes, and nickels, then outputs the total value of coins in pennies

Tags: python

I am struggling to make the code to output the total value of the coins in pennies.

```
print("Please enter the number of coins:")

quarters=int(input("# of quarters:"))

quarters=quarters*25

dimes=int(input("# of dimes:"))

dimes=dimes*10

nickels=int(input("# of nickels:"))

nickels=nickels*5

print("The total is")
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you've already converted the value of each coin in pennies (e.g. quarters = 25 pennies), just add them all together.

```
pennies = quarters + dimes + nickels
print("The total is " + pennies)
```

Answer (score 0):

If all the values are already adjusted according to the expected value, just sum the values:

```
print("Please enter the number of coins:")

quarters = int(input("# of quarters:"))

quarters = quarters*25

dimes = int(input("# of dimes:"))

dimes = dimes*10

nickels = int(input("# of nickels:"))

nickels = nickels*5
```

Options:

```
print(f'The total is {quarters + dimes + nickels} pennies')
```

```
pennies = quarters + dimes + nickels
print(f'The total is {pennies} pennies')
```

```
pennies = sum([quarters,dimes,nickels])
print(f'The total is {pennies} pennies')
```

Output:

```
# of quarters:1
# of dimes:10
# of nickels:100
The total is 625 pennies
```

Comment: Much appreciated. The first post in StackOverflow and honestly I'm shocked at how friendly everyone is!

Answer (score 0):

You need to add all the values together.  Rather than multiplying `quarters` by 25 and so on (you don't actually have n * 25 *quarters*, you have n * 25 *cents*, and it's easy to get confused by your own code when the variables don't contain the things that their names say they do), I'd suggest adding and multiplying them all together when it's time for the final answer:

```
print("Please enter the number of coins:")
quarters = int(input("# of quarters:"))
dimes = int(input("# of dimes:"))
nickels = int(input("# of nickels:"))
print("The total is", quarters * 25 + dimes * 10 + nickels * 5)
```

Another option might be to keep a running total in a single `cents` variable, like this:

```
print("Please enter the number of coins:")
cents = 0
cents += int(input("# of quarters:")) * 25
cents += int(input("# of dimes:")) * 10
cents += int(input("# of nickels:")) * 5
print("The total is", cents)
```

And once you learn about iteration, you can use that general pattern to do it really simply by just making a list of the coin types and iterating over it:

```
print("Please enter the number of coins:")
print("The total is", sum(
    int(input(f"# of {coin}s: ")) * cents
    for coin, cents in [("quarter", 25), ("dime", 10), ("nickel", 5)]
))
```

Comment: Hello again, I am trying to add proper input validation to the app, like if users puts extremely large number to ask to enter the right number, if the number is negative to pit positive if it puts letters to ask users to enter an integer.  Like ATM; after the program is done; ask users to press Y to continue (enter a new integer) or press N to exit the program; what if the user put neither Y nor N

Comment: I'd suggest wrapping `input` in a function that asks for input in a loop and only returns it once it validates.  Search for "python loop valid input" and you'll find a lot of good code examples!

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an overly complicated way of looking at it but I like to create classes for organization reasons and you could easily do:

```
class MoneyCounter:
   def __init__(self):
      self.total=0 #Pennies
      self.penny=1
      self.nickel=5
      self.dime=10
      self.quarter=25
      self.HalfDollar=50
  def addPenny(self,q:int):
      self.total+=self.penny*q
  def addNickel(self,q:int):
      self.total+=self.nickel*q
  def addDime(self,q:int):
      self.total+=self.dime*q
  def addQuarter(self,q:int):
      self.total+=self.quarter*q
  def addHalfDollar(self,q:int):
      self.total+= self.HalfDollar*q
  def total(self):
      return self.total
```

This allows me to create multiple uses of this but also if you did it this way, it is a nice way to introduce you into the idea of how classes work and what things like self and how you can initiate the class. But it can be used like so:

```
counter=MoneyCounter()
print("Please enter the number of coins:")

counter.addQuarter(int(input("# of quarters:")))
counter.addDime(int(input("# of dimes:")))
counter.addNickel(int(input("# of nickels:")))
counter.addPenny(int(input("# of pennies:"))) 
print("The total is ", str(counter.total())) #Total pennies
```

I could also expand this into formatting total() using `match...case`
I would not use this for such a basic application unless you wanted a more in depth intro to Python this was how I originally was thrown in and found this a helpful way of understanding structures.

Comment: hm, it seems like none of your functions work… you’re passing them parameters but not defining them in your function definitions? Also these would only add 1 coin each call?

Comment: sorry was quick writing i fixed it so ```q``` represents quantity of the coins

Answer (score -1):

By defining all coins on the same unit, you can easily convert to any unit

```
#Defining all coins in terms of pennies:
penny = 1  # penny is the amount of pennies in 1 penny
quarter = 25 * penny  # quarter is the amount of pennies in 1 quarter
dime = 10 * penny  # dime is the amount of pennies in 1 dime
nickel = 5 * penny  # nickel is the amount of pennies in 1 nickel

print("Please enter the number of coins:")

quarters = int(input("# of quarters:"))
dimes = int(input("# of dimes:"))
nickels = int(input("# of nickels:"))
pennies = int(input("# of pennies:"))

answer = quarters*quarter + dimes*dime + nickels*nickel + pennies*penny

#Convert to dimes
print("The total in dimes is ",answer/dime)

#Convert the result to any unit
[print(f"The total is {answer/coin[0]} {coin[1]}")
for coin in [(quarter, "quarters"), (dime, "dimes"), (nickel, "nickels"), (penny, "pennies")]]
```